# Slow Count query

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I had created a query to find how many transactions  are made by each ticket in a branch queues.

So I had the `Tickets_table` that has the fields `Branch`, `number_of_ticket`, `issue_date` and `Ticket_call_time`, `Ticket_End_time` (which is the time the ticket stopped being served)

The `Transaction_table` has the transactions that are made in each Branch each day. The fields of `Transaction_Table` are `Branch`, `Date`, and `Transaction_time`.  In order to find which transactions are made by each ticket I created a query that connects the two tables on branch and date and on `Ticket_table.Ticket_call_time<=Transaction_table.Transaction_time` and `Ticket_table.Ticket_End_time>=Transaction_table.End_time` as below:

```
SELECT 
    Transaction_table.Branch, 
    Tickets_table.Ticket, 
    Tickets_table.Date, 
    Transactions_Table.Transaction_Time, 
    Ticket_table.Ticket_call_time, 
    Ticket_table.Ticket_End_time, 
    QTicket_table.Ticket_Call_time, 
    Transaction_table.Transaction_code, 
    [Branch] & [Date] & [Ticket] AS branchdateticket
FROM 
    Transactions_Table 
    INNER JOIN 
    Tickets_Table 
        ON (Transaction_table.Branch = Ticket_table.Branch) AND 
            Transaction_table.Date = Ticket_table.Date AND 
            Ticket_table.Ticket_call_time<=Transaction_table.Transaction_time AND 
            Ticket_table.Ticket_End_time>=Transaction_table.End_time);
```

This query works fine.

I have a table that for the combination of each ticket, branch, and date has the transactions made, but has millions of rows.  I have tried to make another query to count the number of transactions for the last column `branchdateticket`, which is the classic:

```
SELECT 
    branchdateticket, 
    count(Transaction_code)
FROM 
    the_query_above
GROUP BY 
    branchdateticket
```

This query takes about one day to run.

Can you please helm me make it faster?

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the filter clauses outside the join:

```
SELECT Transaction_table.Branch, Tickets_table.Ticket, Tickets_table.Date, Transactions_Table.Transaction_Time, Ticket_table.Ticket_call_time, Ticket_table.Ticket_End_time, QTicket_table.Ticket_Call_time, Transaction_table.Transaction_code, [Branch] & [Date] & [Ticket] AS branchdateticket
FROM Transactions_Table 
INNER JOIN Tickets_Table 
    ON (Transaction_table.Branch = Ticket_table.Branch) AND  Transaction_table.Date = Ticket_table.Date)
WHERE
Ticket_table.Ticket_call_time <= Transaction_table.Transaction_time and Ticket_table.Ticket_End_time >= Transaction_table.End_time;
```

or split the query in two - the first without the where clause; the second having the first query as source and the where clause included.

Comment: The problem is on the second query where i count how many transactions are made by each ticket. It's too slow because the branchdateticket columns has too many distinct values and it's too big